# Getting MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

PFB the tables relation for which getting the MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNT_CONTROL_INSTANCE")
public class ControlInstance {
    /** Added Generator strategy */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = 
    @Parameter(name = "property", value = "variable"))
    private Long                id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Variable            variable;

    @OneToOne(fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "controlInstance")
    private Attribute           attribute;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DYF_ATTRIBUTE")
public class Attribute {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ControlInstance     controlInstance;
}
```

Please let me know the issue and the solution? Issue as I checked in mysql the autoincrement counter for both the tables were not in sync.

Comment: As autoincremet out of sync can you update it? Also you need to check are you have hibernate_sequence table in schema. It could be hibernate take index value from it, instead of autoincrement

Comment: Tried Updating the autoincrement and after few runs again it will go out of sync and dont see any hibernate_sequence table in schema

Comment: Can you try this on id property:  @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
 private Long id;

Comment: And what is your hibernate version?

Comment: HIbernate version - 4.3.11